# Log in a webpage which uses github OAuth

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, oauth, httr

I want to log in https://adventofcode.com/2021 programatically using `httr`.

I have only a very superficial understanding of the `OAuth` "dance", so to understand the principles I did the following:

1. Create an `OAuth App` on GitHub
2. Used the following code to authenticate (*N.B.* I know I could simply use `oauth2.0_token` but I felt that this workflow helped me to better understand the different messages, which are exchanged).

```r
library(httr)

client_id <- "<my client id>"
base_url <- "https://github.com"
path <- "login/oauth/authorize"
client_secret <- "<my secret>"

url <- modify_url(base_url, path = path, 
                  query = list(client_id = client_id, 
                               redirect_uri = oauth_callback()))
code <- oauth_listener(url) ## needed to provide credentials in the web browser
access_token <- POST(modify_url(base_url, path = "login/oauth/access_token"),
                     add_headers(Accept = "application/json"),
                     body = list(client_id = client_id,
                                 client_secret = client_secret,
                                 code = code$code))
## successfully returns the values
GET("https://api.github.com/rate_limit", 
    add_headers(Authorization = paste(content(access_token)$access_token,
                                      "OAUTH-TOKEN")))
```

From this example I think I understand the steps as highlighted in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps).

However, I fail to see how I could use this to login to https://adventofcode.com/2021. I have, of course, not the `client_secret` nor can I redirect the response to my `localhost` (as GitHub requires that the stored callback matches the redirect URI).

Thus, I was wondering how I could programatically login to https://adventofcode.com/2021 to fetch my task data, say?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your application? If you want to use github to get to parts of adventofcode.com that require autorization, you need to use a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mismatching [OAuth2 roles](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.1). If you want to use adventofcode.com, you are a resource owner, adventofcode.com is a client and github is an authorization server. So you authenticate, adventofcode.com gets an auth code and then tokens. They can use the tokens to get information about your github account.

The example code you posted is different - your application is a client that gets a code and tokens from the authorization server (github) after a user was authenticated and gave a consent to passing the tokens to your app (permission delegation). So you probably cannot include adventofcode.com into this scenario.

The only way is if adventofcode.com takes a role of a resource server and their API accepts github tokens from different clients. But I know nothing about their API.

Comment: Yes, I know and that's what I thought. Is it then OK to say that it is impossible to log on to a page which uses the OAuth protocol via scripting (unless the page itself offers an API for that)? What I eventually want is to retrieve some data from AoC whihc is only available once I logged on **w/o** using the browser?

Comment: Yes, it should be like that. There is a possibility that the AoC backend doesn't check the access token properly (the backend API called from their website) and if you send your token there, it will work, but I would not count on that.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it would have been too easy. Thanks for the clarification!