# R to get data with login

Tags: r, authentication, get

I am trying to automate the collection of data for the AdventOfCode challenge this year. As a test example, I am trying to download the data for [2020 day 6](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/6/input). But I am running into problems accessing the data as it requires a log in first. I've tried using the below (with my github username and password) but no luck, and several other variants. Any advice on how to get past this? It could be as simple as a different variant of the username, e.g. "github.com/username" but I'm not getting any useful feedback from the request so it's hard to diagnose!

```
library(httr)
GET('https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/6/input', 
    authenticate('username', 'password'))
```

Comment: Using your github account for authenticating there is going to require an OAuth (Oauth2?) flow. I suggest you look into using _tokens_, perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206455/log-in-a-webpage-which-uses-github-oauth is useful?

Comment: Are you sure the website supports basic http authentication? Other examples I see trying to download from that site supplies user information via cookies rather than http headers. Any solution would be site/url specific. Websites are free to handle authentication anyway they way and there is no way that will universally work for all sites.

Comment: Thanks both - @mrflick that solved it, I will post the solution as an answer

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74753781/scraping-the-data-of-the-advent-of-code-in-js) in Node, with basically the same fundamental answer.

Answer (score 1):

As MrFlick recommened, the solution was via cookies. To get the relevant cookies info, log in to advent of code, (in chrome) *inspect* > *application* > *storage/cookies* and add the four values to `cookie` below:

```
library(httr)

session <- '<session>'

get_aoc <- function(day, year, ck=session){
  rawToChar(GET(paste0('https://adventofcode.com/', year,'/day/', day, '/input'), 
                set_cookies(session=ck))$content)
}


get_aoc(1, 2023)
```

Comment: For AOC you only need a `session` cookie. And there's `httr::content(response, as = "text")`